# Does Django QuerySet use binary search to filter by date?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a Location object in my Django app that uses Simple History (https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history), and I need to frequently query that object for its history between two dates. I know you can do that with:

```
Location.objects.filter(id=1, history_date__range=(starttime, endtime))
```

However, I noticed that all history for a given id is ordered from latest to earliest. That means I should be able to do a binary search on that list to get all dates included.

My question is -- is hard coding a python binary search after

```
Location.objects.filter(id=1)
```

faster or slower than just using the Query described above?

Comment: I don't know, but have you tried timing it?

Comment: I don't actually know how it works, but I'd bet it punts the actual implementation to whatever database you're using.

Comment: I have tried timing it, but I don't think my history is long enough to get a meaningful measure yet, because it takes about the same amount of time. (History is only about 3000 items long at this point, but will get much larger over time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the database you're using. In most databases, there's an implicit "natural ordering" of rows: when the row was inserted into the database. This might be how it's displaying, which doesn't guarantee ordering.

If you're concerned with computation time, you can place an index on history_date, so grabbing an ordered list is O(log(n)) time. However, inserting, updating, and deleting will take slightly longer!